# Call method using TPL with limit of maximum 10 request

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-6.0

- I have 1000 records to process pending items. So, I need to call a C# method which is in TPL (parallel mechanism) but with the max request of 10. So that I can process 10 requests at a time in a batch process.
- Also, is there any way to find if any request is completed or not from the previous 10 requests So that if one gets over in the request then request another new item to process but should not exceed the max request count which is 10.